# I'm using Azure bot virtual assistant and need help in getting LUIS intent

Tags: botframework

Need to find top luis intent once in virtual assistant dispatch model

Here is MainDialog.cs code

```cs
protected override async Task RouteAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // Get cognitive models for locale
    var locale = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    var cognitiveModels = _services.CognitiveModelSets[locale];

    // Check dispatch result
    var dispatchResult = await cognitiveModels.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync<DispatchLuis>(dc.Context, CancellationToken.None);
    var intent = dispatchResult.TopIntent().intent;

    if (intent == DispatchLuis.Intent.Test)
    {
        //How to get Top LUIS intent?????????
        //??? 
        //???
    }

}
```

Comment: Fixing code and presentation

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it either this way or do some custom logic:

```
protected override async Task RouteAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))

    {

        // Get cognitive models for locale

        var locale = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        var cognitiveModels = _services.CognitiveModelSets[locale];



        // Check dispatch result

        var dispatchResult = await cognitiveModels.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync<DispatchLuis>(dc.Context, CancellationToken.None);

        var intent = dispatchResult.TopIntent().intent;



        // Identify if the dispatch intent matches any Action within a Skill if so, we pass to the appropriate SkillDialog to hand-off

        var identifiedSkill = SkillRouter.IsSkill(_settings.Skills, intent.ToString());



        if (identifiedSkill != null)

        {

            // We have identiifed a skill so initialize the skill connection with the target skill

            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(identifiedSkill.Id);



            // Pass the activity we have

            var result = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();



            if (result.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Complete)

            {

                await CompleteAsync(dc);

            }

        }

        else if (intent == DispatchLuis.Intent.l_general)

        {

            // If dispatch result is general luis model

            cognitiveModels.LuisServices.TryGetValue("general", out var luisService);



            if (luisService == null)

            {

                throw new Exception("The general LUIS Model could not be found in your Bot Services configuration.");

            }

            else

            {

                var result = await luisService.RecognizeAsync<GeneralLuis>(dc.Context, CancellationToken.None);



                var generalIntent = result?.TopIntent().intent;



                // switch on general intents

                switch (generalIntent)

                {

                    case GeneralLuis.Intent.Escalate:

                        {

                            // start escalate dialog

                            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(EscalateDialog));

                            break;

                        }



                    case GeneralLuis.Intent.None:

                    default:

                        {

                            // No intent was identified, send confused message

                            await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Confused);

                            break;

                        }

                }

            }

        }

        else if (intent == DispatchLuis.Intent.q_faq)

        {

            cognitiveModels.QnAServices.TryGetValue("faq", out var qnaService);



            if (qnaService == null)

            {

                throw new Exception("The specified QnA Maker Service could not be found in your Bot Services configuration.");

            }

            else

            {

                var answers = await qnaService.GetAnswersAsync(dc.Context, null, null);



                if (answers != null && answers.Count() > 0)

                {

                    await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(answers[0].Answer, speak: answers[0].Answer);

                }

                else

                {

                    await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Confused);

                }

            }

        }

        else if (intent == DispatchLuis.Intent.q_chitchat)

        {

            cognitiveModels.QnAServices.TryGetValue("chitchat", out var qnaService);



            if (qnaService == null)

            {

                throw new Exception("The specified QnA Maker Service could not be found in your Bot Services configuration.");

            }

            else

            {

                var answers = await qnaService.GetAnswersAsync(dc.Context, null, null);



                if (answers != null && answers.Count() > 0)

                {

                    await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(answers[0].Answer, speak: answers[0].Answer);

                }

                else

                {

                    await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Confused);

                }

            }

        }

        else

        {

            // If dispatch intent does not map to configured models, send "confused" response.

            await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Confused);

        }

    }
```

I have taken this from the official Microsoft samples. Do let me know if there any doubts.
Please have a look at this:https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Template/VA/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs

Answer (score 0):

In your code, var intent should already have the top intent from the dispatch bot stored in it.
If you want to see which intent is stored in it you can just have the bot print it.

```
await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(intent.ToString());
```